# Unity2D not checking conditions properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I've been asking so many Unity questions in such little time and I really appreciate all those who answer. I don't know why I always face such issues for which any of the answers I see on the net aren't able to help me out. Okay so here's my problem:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) && (rightHit.collider != null || leftHit.collider != null) && groundHit.collider == null)
```

This line of code here in the Update function checks every frame if I'm holding down the Q button on any wall. If the condition is satisfied, then

```
void Grapple()
    {
        if (wallGrapple) 
        {
            x = 0f;
            rb.gravityScale = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * x, speed * y);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { jumpRequest = true; }

        }
    }
```

this function is called which allows the player to stick and slide on the wall based on Vertical axis input(which feeds the y variable). Now the problem is that if I only press Q once on a wall then it stays on the wall even though its supposed to be held down for Grapple() to be called [I've used Input.GetKey instead of Input.GetKeyDown] and I am also able to slide above the wall (like there's some sorta invisible wall) even though in the if line, the condition for detecting a wall is being checked. 
[image: see, no wall and still moving only vertically]

I've been at it for around 30-45 minutes and I'm unable to crack it. Another workaround I thought of implementing was using a coroutine but I don't know how to use as I haven't found any basic explanation of how it works and how its supposed to be used. Here's the full code,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask Wall;

    [Header("Horizontal")]
    public float x;
    float dirX;
    public float speed;
    float initialSpeed;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float LerpConstant;
    public float dashForce = 100f;
    public bool canDash;
    public bool dashRequest;
    [Header("Vertical")]
    public float y;
    public bool canJump;
    public bool jumpRequest;
    public float initialJumpForce;
    public float jumpForce;
    public bool canWallJump;
    public float modifiedJumpForce;
    public float sideJumpForce;
    public bool wallGrapple;
    [Header("Other")]
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float gScale = 10f;
    BoxCollider2D boxcollider;


    RaycastHit2D groundHit;
    RaycastHit2D leftHit;
    RaycastHit2D rightHit;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boxcollider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        jumpForce = initialJumpForce;
        initialSpeed = speed;
        rb.gravityScale = gScale;

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Instant 1, 0, -1 inputs
        x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        if(x < 0) 
            { dirX = -1; } 
        else if(x > 0) 
            { dirX = 1; }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (canJump || canWallJump)) //for jumps
            { jumpRequest = true; } 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) && (rightHit.collider != null || leftHit.collider != null) && groundHit.collider == null) //for wall grappling
            { wallGrapple = true; } 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && (canDash)) //for dashing
            { dashRequest = true; } 

        Detection();
        JumpDash();
        Grapple();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {        
        Movement();
    }

    void Detection()
    {
        groundHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxcollider.bounds.center, boxcollider.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundMask);
        if (groundHit.collider != null) //If player is on ground
        {
            canJump = true;
            canWallJump = false;
            canDash = false;
            jumpForce = initialJumpForce;
            sideJumpForce = 0;
            LerpConstant = 0.25f;
        }
        else if (groundHit.collider == null)//not on ground 
        {
            LerpConstant = 0.12f;
            canJump = false;
        }

        //Wall detection

        //Left wall
        leftHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxcollider.bounds.center, boxcollider.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.left, 0.1f, Wall);
        if (leftHit.collider != null && groundHit.collider == null) //if player on left wall and not on ground
        {
            canWallJump = true;
            jumpForce = modifiedJumpForce;
            sideJumpForce = jumpForce;

        }
        //Right wall
        rightHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxcollider.bounds.center, boxcollider.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.right, 0.1f, Wall);
        if (rightHit.collider != null && groundHit.collider == null) //if player on right wall and not on ground
        {
            canWallJump = true;
            jumpForce = modifiedJumpForce;
            sideJumpForce = -jumpForce; // negative of jump force to jump in left direction


        }

        if (rightHit.collider == null && leftHit.collider == null) //if both walls are not detected
        {
            canWallJump = false;
        }
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        Vector2 move = new Vector2(x * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(rb.velocity, move, LerpConstant);
    }



    void JumpDash()
    {

        //Jump
        if (jumpRequest)
        {
            wallGrapple = false;
            rb.gravityScale = gScale;
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(sideJumpForce * 2.1f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            speed = initialSpeed;
            jumpRequest = false; //setting jumpRequest to false after jumping to prevent unlimited jumps
            canDash = true;
        }

        /*if (dashRequest)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.AddForce((dashForce, 0f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }*/ //remember to put this code in later

    }

    void Grapple()
    {
        if (wallGrapple) 
        {
            x = 0f;
            rb.gravityScale = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * x, speed * y);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { jumpRequest = true; }

        }
    }

}
```

P.S. I originally wanted to use Space itself instead of Q for the stick and slide but more errors pop up like inconsistent wall jumping so that's why I used Q.

https://streamable.com/3v6qrq <- Video showing the problem.

Comment: despite all your explanations, i dont understant your problem...where is your problem

Comment: Okay I've uploaded a video showing the problem. Also I want it such that the player sticks (and slides on) to the wall when I hold down Q instead of pressing it just once. Also you can see in the video that the player can go above the wall even though the if condition should not let it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't set

> wallGrapple = false

anywhere in your code except in the jump request. Therefore, as it never gets set to false your player will continuously grapple.
Maybe you can set it to false in the Update function first and do the key detection.

Comment: Okay this almost worked for me. Now when I go above the wall, my player will just continuously go up. I set wallGrapple = false in the update function which should mean that its false all the time, only being true when the conditions are satisfied. I know how this works but shouldn't my previous code set wallGrapple to false automatically when the conditions are not satisfied? Or does it just remain what it was when the conditions stop dissatisfied?

Comment: No - you need to explicitly set the wallGrapple=false somewhere, be it in the beginning of update or detection etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing you a coroutine example code snippet.
You can understand it from the comment lines and apply it to your own code.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("coroutineFunc");  // calling for example 
}
```

and coroutine func like this:

```
IEnumerator coroutineFunc()
    {
         // before waiting... if u wanna try something
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); // waiting..

            // after waiting something what do you want



    }
```

Comment: How exactly would coroutine work in this situation? From my understanding, I know that calling a coroutine would stop all the code from running except the coroutine, yes? So that means I can call the coroutine when if conditions are satisfied, right? Also what would we put before waiting exactly? (Sorry I'm so confused, an example would help me out). Last thing is will it check the conditions accurately (unlike the current code which is not checking the conditions properly)?

Comment: It makes sense to use the letter q. however, the question you ask is very specific, in which case you have to decide for yourself what you need to operate.
I can only guide you. No other functions will work while coroutine is running. review the conditions you wrote and check their debug and states. I would be happy to help if you can clarify the problem a little more. Personally, I don't need coroutine when I read your problem.

Comment: I hope this comment clarifies the problem now, which is that when I press Q on the wall, it sticks even though I want it to stick only when the player HOLDS down Q (and so I have used if(Input.GetKey .....) instead of if(Input.GetKeyDown ....) but it still behaves like KeyDown) and the player when stuck on the wall is also able to slide ABOVE the wall which should not be possible because the If condition is that the player can only grapple/stick to wall when it detects a wall so when it goes above the wall, the condition becomes false but it's still true for some reason.

Comment: Okay, I also tried using IEnumerator but I don't know what I've done is correct. `IEnumerator Grapple()
    {
        x = 0f;
        rb.gravityScale = 0;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * x, speed * y);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { jumpRequest = true; }
        yield return null;            
        
    } `  The code is apparently working but I think I haven't used it properly. And also, the issue of the if conditions not being detected accurately still persists.